# C - Dynamic array of struct error

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to implement a multithreaded C program and I'm stuck.
I have a struct which holds a char array and a pointer to another struct (I'm trying to use that pointer as an array of **buffer_item**s:

```
typedef struct{

    char** buffer;
} buffer_item;

typedef struct{

    buffer_item* buffers;
    char file_name[255];

}buffer_holder;
```

When I try to create **buffer_item**s and put them into **buffer_holder**'s buffers array, gcc gives me the following error:

```
for(i = 0; i < n_value; i++){

        buffer_holder *holder = (buffer_holder*) malloc(sizeof(buffer_holder));
        int l;

        for(l = 0; l < r_value; l++){

            buffer_item *new_item  = (buffer_item *)malloc(sizeof(buffer_item));
            new_item->buffer = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char*));
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < buffer_size; j++)
                new_item->buffer[j] = malloc((MAX_WORD+1) * sizeof(char));

            holder -> buffers[l] = new_item;
        }
        strcpy(holder -> file_name, argv[i+3]);

        if(pthread_create(&mapper_threads[i], NULL, mapper, (void*) holder)) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

> wcountb2.c:187:28: error: incompatible types when assigning to type
>   ‘buffer_item’ from type ‘struct buffer_item *’
>          holder -> buffers[l] = new_item;

I have been trying to solve it but could not find anything.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: `holder->buffers` is an array of `buffer_item` structures, you treat it like an array of *pointers* to `buffer_item` structures.

Comment: I see, how can I change the code accordingly?

Comment: Oh, and you don't actually allocate memory for `holder->buffers`, so it's uninitialized and the pointers value will be *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) so when you do `holder->buffers[l]` you dereference this uninitialized pointer and you get [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

`holder->buffers` is a pointer to `struct buffer_item`, but in the assignment `holder->buffers[l] = new_item` you treat it like an array of pointers.

to fix it just change `holder->buffers[l] = new_item;` into `holder->buffers = new_item;`